# TYPO3: Inline Notation for If Statement with nested For Loop

Tags: nested, typo3, inline, view-helpers

I'm trying to get the following code as inline notation:

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.tags}">
    <f:for each="{newsItem.tags}" as="tag">
        {tag.title}
    </f:for>
</f:if>
```

I've managed to get the if statement like this:

```
{f:if(condition: newsItem.tags, then: ',')}
```

That works perfectly, now I only need to put the for loop inside the "then: ' ' " part.

I tried that, but it gets messy and always ouputs a text not with the listed tags as intended.

I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
{f:if(condition: newsItem.tags, then: '{tag.title -> f:for(each: newsItem.tags, as: "tag")}')}
```

I normally use http://www.fluid-converter.com/ to help in those cases. It does not support complex example, but if you use it viewhelper for viewhelper it certainly helps.

Comment: I actually had the exact same thing, I used it inside the metatag tx_news viewhelper which seems to be bugged, because it will not render out as a meta tag when the nested for loop is present. I'm now using it inside the n:headerData viewhelper which has no problems with it.